# datagridview clear and cellvalidate issue

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` containing multiple columns. The first column is an identifier, which must be a unique 1 or 2 digit number. I use cell validating to ensure that the identifier satisfies these criteria. The user enters data, as many rows as needed, then exports the data. After exporting the data the program clears the `dataGridView` by calling `grid.Clear()` and `grid.Refresh()`.

This works well most of the time but sometimes when the rows are being deleted I get an error indicating the cell number in column 1 is not unique. I can't consistently reproduce this error; when I enter the debugger typically if I try and break at the cell validating step I find that it's not being called during the clear, as I expect. However sometimes it does break there during the clear and that of course causes problems.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this problem?

Edit: Here's my cellValidate code:

```
private void Grid_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string headerText = Grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

        switch (headerText)
        {
            case "Number":

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
                {
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), @"(^\d{1,2}$)"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Identifier number must be a 1 or 2 digit positive number");
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in Grid.Rows)
                        {
                            if (r.Cells[0].Value != null)
                            {
                                if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == r.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                                {
                                    //this message box pops up sometimes when I call Grid.Clear()
                                    MessageBox.Show("Identifier number must unique");
                                    e.Cancel = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break; //more cases for each column
```

Comment: Can you post any code examples to show what the datasource looks like?

Comment: I haven't bound the datasource to anything, it begins as an empty dataGridView that the user adds to.

Comment: if you could post your code we may figure it out what will be the possible problem.

Comment: My guess is that it occurs when a cell in this column has focus and then you call `Clear`. Maybe the cell is validated even if it has not been changed.

Comment: @RoadBump: When/why would the cell have focus? Is there a way to test this?

Comment: When it's selected, or user started editing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was sometimes clearing the dataGridView with a cell in the identifier column selected and thus in focus. By turning multi-select off and changing the focus to a different cell before calling clear() I was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean value in Grid_CellValidating event and bypass it and after clearing the Datagridview you can reset the boolean value